# rating of numbers in excel according their position

Tags: excel

suppose we have following numbers

```
91.21
55.56
63.92
87.67
71.25
75.58
53.08
71.17
60.04
65.21
96.08
83.88
66.71
40.46
57.79
25.04
0.17
52.78
46.83
93.58
73.83
41.21
89.67
67
85.13
0
32.65
68.08
9.83
23.5
93.17
69.29
40.17
74.17
70.88
69.54
97.96
46.75
47.42
99.33
6.42
24.58
24.83
55.75
```

I want to rank these numbers. For example, 91.21 is the second largest number, so it should have 2, and 55.56 is 10th largest number, so it should have 10, etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean RATEs or RANKs? To get the RANK (i.e. largest number is 1) there is a function `RANK.EQ(A1,A1:A99)` that will give you that (91.21 is 6th largest)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could just use the [RANK](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/rank-function-HP010335659.aspx) function:
=RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$44)

Comment: You should really use `RANK.AVG` or `RANK.EQ` as `RANK` is just for backward compatibility - it might go sometime in the future... The difference in the two is down to their handling of multiples of the same value

Answer (score 0):

You ca use:

=MATCH(INDEX(List; MATCH(SMALL(COUNTIF(List; "<"&List); ROW(1:1)); COUNTIF(List; "<"&List); 0));List;0)

And autocomplete. The formula it's an array, than you need to insert with Ctrl + Shift + Enter
**Where:**
List, it's the Name of the Range you want to index.

Comment: name or range of numbers?

Comment: i have done  like this =MATCH(INDEX(C4:C47,MATCH(SMALL(COUNTIF(C4:C47, "<"&C4:C47), ROW(1:1)), COUNTIF(C4:C47, "<"&C4:C47), 0)),C4:C47,0)